# No internet after installing Hyper-V

Tags: windows, networking, connection, hyper-v

I'm currently in Windows 10 Pro (1803).
 After I installed Hyper-V I had no internet connection (My windows 10 pro has no internet connection).
I need to uninstall Hyper-V so as to get the internet.
 Although it said I have plugged in the ethernet, it said it doesn't have any internet connection.

What do I need to provide so that you can help me?

Comment: welcome to superuser. this is a Q and A site only no chat on answer pages. as for what we may need - who told you you have to uninstall hyper-v. where does it say you are connected to ethernet, in hyper or the desktop indicator. [answer]. again welcome

Comment: I don't know what to do to have internet access. So I uninstall hyper-v. Also, it said I have connected to the ethernet in the right low corner. It has an ethernet connected icon. But no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you remove all the Virtual Switches that you defined in Hyper-V.
That should restore network connectivity to the host (or allow you to correct the resulting network adapter setting on the host to restore network).

Once you have that working again, then when adding a new virtual switch ensure
that the "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" option
in the Virtual Switch Properties is enabled:

[image]

Comment: I have removed all switches (Except the default one). But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. What happens if you uninstall Hyper-V in Windows features and then re-install, does this get rid of the weirdness?

Comment: Also look for leftover internet adapters in Network Center.

Comment: No it doesn't get rid of the weirdness

Comment: I suggest to roll back to a system restore point from before installing Hyper-V. For some reason Hyper-V doesn't work well on your Windows or hardware.

Comment: I don't have a restart point + I just reinstall the system

Comment: This atomic solution always works.

Comment: What do you mean, I don't get it.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is as final as the atomic bomb ...

Comment: I think that's the only way that I can do